# How parse text with Regex using optional groups as the following preferred java syntax

Tags: regex, regex-group

I want to make regex as group optional

using

https://regex101.com/

The text is as the following:

```
start to proceed task TaskId = id Account = xx@ttt.com Type = value1 Source = source_value SubSource = subSource_value
```

The optional groups are Source,SubSource all the rest are mandatories

I've tried to use as the following , but didn't success to use optional

Regex:

```
 start to proceed task\s*TaskId\s*=\s*(.*)\s*Account\s*=\s*(.*)\s*Type\s*=\s*(.*)\s*Source\s*=\s*(.*)\s*SubSource\s*=\s*(.*)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Group 1.    31-36   `id `
Group 2.    46-57   `xx@ttt.com `
Group 3.    64-71   `value1 `
Group 4.    80-93   `source_value `
Group 5.    105-120 `subSource_value`
```

But when I remove either Source or SubSource or both `Source = source_value SubSource = subSource_value` from the text , no output is shown , my purpuse is to have : (depends on what removed)

```
Group 1.    31-36   `id `
Group 2.    46-57   `xx@ttt.com `
Group 3.    64-71   `value1 `
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working script and pattern:

```
String line = "start to proceed task TaskId = id Account = xx@ttt.com Type = value1 Source = source_value SubSource = subSource_value";
String pattern = "start to proceed task\\s+TaskId\\s*=\\s*(.*?)\\s+Account\\s*=\\s*(.*?)\\s+Type\\s*=\\s*(.*?)(?:\\s+Source\\s*=\\s*(.*?))?\\s+(?:SubSource\\s*=\\s*(.*))?";

Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Group 1: " + m.group(1) );
    System.out.println("Group 2: " + m.group(2) );
    System.out.println("Group 3: " + m.group(3) );
    System.out.println("Group 4: " + m.group(4) );
    System.out.println("Group 5: " + m.group(5) );
}

Group 1: id
Group 2: xx@ttt.com
Group 3: value1
Group 4: source_value
Group 5: subSource_value
```

### Demo

The crux of the changes I made include making the capture groups lazy `(.*?)`.  Also, I made the entire pattern for the source and sub source optional, e.g.

```
(?:\s+Source\s*=\s*(.*?))?
```

Notice that the surrounding group begins with `?:`, which tells the regex engine *not* to capture this.  So only your original `(.*?)` group might be captured, assuming the text has it.

In order to get the pattern to work, I needed to assume `\s+` instead of `\s*` in certain places.

Comment: This doesn't work because the third group captures the subsequent optional groups.

Comment: @Mark I made all the `(.*?)` capture groups lazy.  They should not consume past the next available whitespace.

Comment: Was messing around with it trying to get it to work without assuming `\s+` instead of `\s*`. I suspect it is possible with some duplicate groups, ORs, and maybe lookaheads. Would be some ugly regex though.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen , Thanks a lot , looking great :) , Btw, what means '?' at the end of group '(?:\s+Source\s*=\s*(.*?))?' ....

Comment: @VitalyT That means match zero or one times.

Comment: @Mark I only assumed spaces between `X=Y` terms, which actually seems correct to me (otherwise how do we know the separation between terms).  Within a term, there can be zero or more spaces, and I left it alone.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I agree that it's a reasonable assumption/compromise. I was just curious if it's possible. It is: `(.*?)\s*?(?=Source|SubSource|$)(?:Source\s*=\s*(.*?))?\s*?(?=SubSource|$)(?:SubSource\s*=\s*(.*))?`